# Scheffe's lemma with dominated convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

> Suppose that $f_n, f$ are non-negative measurable functions with $\mu(f_n)$ and $\mu (f)$ finite and such that $f_n\to f \text{ a.e.}$, Then  $\mu(|f_n-f|)\to 0 \iff \mu(f_n)\to\mu(f)$.

For $\mu(f_n)\to\mu(f) \Rightarrow \mu(|f_n-f|)\to 0$

Using dominated convergence theorem, setting $g_n=f-f_n$ and first assuming that $\mu(f_n) \to \mu(f)$ and $|f_n-f|\to 0 \text{ a.e.}$

Then $\mu(|g_n|)=2\mu(g^+_n)-\mu(g_n)\to 0$ because $0\leq g~_n^+\leq f$ and $|f_n-f|\to 0\text{ a.e.}$

Why can you assume that $|f_n-f|\to 0 \text{ a.e.}$? Is it equivalent to $f_n\to f \text{ a.e.}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
$$
f_n\to f\;\text{ a.e.} \iff |f_n-f|\to\;\text{ a.e.}
$$
This is simply because
$$
f_n(x)\to f(x)\iff |f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0,\quad \text{for any } x\in X,
$$
so you can use the same null-set.