# Proof for Scheffe's Lemma and General Dominated Convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

While reading this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364059/doubt-in-scheffes-lemma) about the proof for Scheffe's Lemma,
I was confused since someone said the proof in the question was not correct. I thought the argument was fine, and the author only needed to use the General Dominated Convergence theorem to finish the argument. Continuing form his/her work, we have that 
$$\lim_n \int f + f_n = \int 2f < \infty$$
which implies $\lim_n \int|f-f_n| = 0$.

**General Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem**: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions that converges pointwise a.e to $f$. Suppose there is a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of nonnegative measurable functions that converges pointwise a.e to $g$ and dominateds $f_n$ in the sense that 
$$|f_n| \leq g_n.$$

$$\text{If } \lim_n \int g_n = \int g < \infty, \text{ then } \lim_n \int f_n = \int f.$$

Comment: what is your question? do you mean the accepted answer to the question you linked?

Comment: @Lost1 Is my argument correct with the GLDCM? Because people in the other thread said that you can not use a sequence of functions as bounding function(s).

Comment: I think your argument is fine but the way the OP in the other question wrote it is wrong. ( I have never seen this result you quoted before, but I just looked it up )

Comment: I think the answer to that is not quite correct. it was given as a condition that $\int f_n\rightarrow\int f$

Comment: @Lost1 OP in the other question didn't use the assumption $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$ in order to apply the GLDCT, but his/her argument before was ok I believe. This is what I wanted to check.

Comment: yes ^ of course and nice proof. you should post an answer to that question :)