Prove convergence of integrals and discuss failure without integrability condition
Let $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq L^{+}$ be a sequence of non-negative functions such that $\lim _{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} f_n \, d\mu = \int_{X} f \, d\mu < \infty$.
(a) Prove that
$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n \, d\mu = \int_{E} f \, d\mu
$
for all $E \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets.
(b) Show that the above statement can fail without the assumption that $\int_{X} f \, d\mu < \infty$.
(a): For any $E \in \mathcal{A}$, $\lim _{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)\mathbf{1}_E = f(x)\mathbf{1}_E,$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} f_n\mathbf{1}_E \, d\mu = \int_{X} f \, d\mu < \infty$. Then, I want to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n \, d\mu =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} f_n \mathbf{1}_E\, d\mu =\int_{x} f \mathbf{1}_E\, d\mu=\int_{E} f \, d\mu.$ But when using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, I didn't know whether there exists an integrable function g such that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ for almost all $x \in X$. So is this process correct?
(b) I have a counterexamples, but I am not sure it is right:
Consider the measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, where $X = [0, \infty)$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Define the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if } 1 \leq x \leq n, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$.
For each fixed $x \in [1, \infty)$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.
Thus, $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.
The integral of each $f_n$ over $E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [n, \infty)$ is
$
\int_E f_n \, d\mu  = 0.
$
Therefore,
$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, d\mu = 0,
$
but
$
\int_E f \, d\mu = \int_E 1/x \, d\mu \neq 0.
$
Could you tell me whether my answer is true or false? And give some hints. Thanks very much.

A) is very standard and it is called Scheffe's Lemma. Your answer to b) is wrong because $E$ is the empty set, so $\int_E\frac 1 x dx=0$.

Ref. for a): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364059/doubt-in-scheffes-lemma
