# Convergence in probability and $E(|X_n|) \to E(|X|)$ implies convergence in mean

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

It is well known that in probability theory that, if $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$, the following are equivalent.

1. $X_n$ converges in mean to $X$
2. $E(|X_n|) \rightarrow E(|X|) < \infty$
3. $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable

While I was able to find multiple proofs of the above results, all of them prove in the order of (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (1).

I feel that it should be possible to prove (2) -> (1) directly without using the results for uniform integrability. For instance, there is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363271/scheffes-lemma-with-dominated-convergence) for $X_n \ge 0$ only using Dominated Convergence Theorem. Any pointers will be welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proof is surprisingly simple (if we have the right tools). It could be proved by using a variation of the Generalized Dominated convergence theorem, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4401912/136006).

The theorem is stated without proof.

**Theorem** (Dominated convergence theorem).
Let $Z_n$, $Y_n$, $Z$ and $Y$ be R.V.'s such that $|Z_n| \le Y_n$ almost surely, $Z_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} Z$, $Y_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} Y$ and $E(Y_n) \rightarrow E(Y) < \infty$, then $E|Z_n-Z| \rightarrow 0$.

**Question**: Show that if $X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} X$ and $E(|X_n|) \rightarrow E(|X|) < \infty$, then $E|X_n-X| \rightarrow 0$.

**Answer**:
Let $Z_n = |X_n - X|$ and $Y_n = |X_n| + |X|$ clearly that $Z_n \le |X_n| + |X| = Y_n$, $Z_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$, $Y_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 2|X|$ and $E(Y_n) = E|X_n| + E|X|  \rightarrow 2 E|X| = E(2|X|) < \infty$. By applying the above DCT, we have $E|X_n-X| = E|Z_n - 0| \rightarrow 0$.